# Blazor Web Assembly - On refresh getting - HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found - after publishing the app in IIS

Tags: iis, blazor-webassembly

I published a sample blazor WASM app and deployed it in IIS in my local machine. I'm able to access all the pages in from the hosted port,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxjYn.png)
however when i refresh the page on counter or weather i'm getting below error - home page refresh is working the other two pages are having this issue. the browser is looking for a weather document as per what is shown in the network tab
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtCS8.png)
How can i resolve this?

Tried to implement these 2 solutions but not working:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1381741/if-i-publish-blazor-wasm-and-try-to-access-any-new

https://medium.com/swlh/blazor-handling-404s-with-iis-666920a4a60

**SOLUTION:**
You need to install this module: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

If you don't have a web.config file in your project (output) yet, then create a new one with the following content to configure a rewrite rule:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Clear all rules -->
        <clear />
        <!-- Rewrite all requests not pointing to a file or directory to index.html -->
        <rule name="Serve index page" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

ensures that everything doing an initial load will be caught and rewritten to your index.html. Further navigation will then happen inside your Blazor app.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEB7Y.png)

Comment: Do you have the same problem running this application in VS? Does your problem only occur after deploying to IIS? I will test your problem.

Comment: I created a sample Blazor Web App, then published to a local folder and deployed it to IIS. But I haven't been able to reproduce your problem, my site runs fine. When I refresh the page, the application reloads as expected. I checked your picture, web.config is the configuration file for IIS and it should be in the root directory WASM2, not in the wwwroot folder of your application.